# How to set permissions in Fisheye's projects

Tags: permissions, repository, project, atlassian-fisheye

I'm working with Fisheye and I created a few repositories and a few projects referencing them. I want to show them to anonymous users, but although repositories are shown to anonymous users (non-registered), projects aren't.

I went to Administration, Repository Defaults, Permissions, Anonymous Access and set 'Allow anonymous access to the repositories', but how can I do the same with the projects?

Answer (score 2):

The projects tab actually stems from [Crucible](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible/overview) rather than [FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/overview) (you can have one or the other, but they run together if both are available), see the header on the project administration page:

> A project is a set of Crucible content combined with a set of
>   customisable FishEye content.

Consequently this is a Crucible setting, which is orchestrated via *Permission Schemes* under *Security Settings* within *Administration*, thus a bit more complex. You'll have to review and experiment with the various permissions yourself on how to achieve the desired goal (each permission has a separate *Allow Anonymous users* setting), but I venture the guess that adjusting the *View - 
Ability to view a review.* setting accordingly should be all you need.

Comment: "adjusting the View - Ability to view a review. setting accordingly should be all you need" -- that's exactly right